# Grouping data slows query despite 25% decrease in the number of results

Tags: performance, ms-access, vba, group-by

I have an Access database of 4M rows, each representing an individual customer order.

I need to run a query from Excel (I use VBA) in order to retrieve only the orders from customers in `REGION1`.

I tried the following (names should be pretty self-explanatory):

```
Sub Query()

Dim cn As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String

strFile = "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\DataBase.accdb"
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT [CUSTOMER], [DATE], [REVENUE]" _
& "FROM [SALES DB]" _
& "WHERE [REGION]='REGION1'"
rs.Open strSQL, cn, 0, 1

Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

This works nicely but it's a bit slow, as it returns ~600k rows.

So I thought: "Who cares about the detailed list of all customer orders? I just need the monthly aggregate. This should reduce the number of returned rows and hence inprove speed!".

So I changed my code to:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [CUSTOMER], MONTH([DATE]), YEAR([DATE]), SUM([REVENUE])" _
& "FROM [SALES DB]" _
& "WHERE [REGION]='REGION1'"
& "GROUP BY [CUSTOMER], MONTH([DATE]), YEAR([DATE])"
```

As I expected, now only ~450K results show up. The thing is, the query actually became slower.

I'm actually better off extracting the ungrouped data and then aggregating it with a simple pivot table.

How can less data be slower to extract? I know there's some calculations to be performed in between, but still.

Does anybody out there have any idea how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: The problem is Access, Excel and VBA

Comment: Lol, what other options do I have?

Comment: LAMP, http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention the actual time taken by the queries, but here are a few thoughts:

1. Make sure you have indexes for all the fields in the database that you are grouping or filtering.
2. If you are the only user of that database, open it in exclusive mode:
   For `ADO`, use the connection string:

   ```
   "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";Mode=12;"
   ```
3. Use `DAO` instead of `ADO`.
   `DAO` is native to Access and generally faster.

   First thing is to add a reference to the Access Engine to Excel:

   - From the IDE, under Tools > References, go down the list and check:
     `Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library`.
   - If you have Access 2010, the reference will be:
     `Microsoft Office 14.0 Access database engine Object Library`.
   - With older versions of Access (2003 and previous), using the Jet engine instead (MDB files only), it would be:
     `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`.

   Then use the VBA code below to load the data into your worksheet:

```
    Public Sub LoadFromDb()
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        ' Open the database in Exclusive mode '
        Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\DataBase.accdb", True)
        ' Open the recordset as a snapshot, it's faster than the default dbDynaset '
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT CUSTOMER, DATE, REVENUE " & _
                "FROM [SALES DB] WHERE REGION='REGION1'", dbOpenSnapshot)
        ' Copy the recordset to the sheet '
        Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
        db.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
    End Sub
```

1. If you are mostly importing your data from Access to display them in a Pivot, you may be better served by the pivot table in Access itself.
2. On that subject, did you know that you can split your database to share the data backend and use the free [Access Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10910) to allow all your users to view your reports and play with the data on their machine?
3. Moving to SQL Server or another database may/may not solve your issues at all:

   - if SQL Server is on your Machine, it will take more or less as much resources to calculate your query as if the MS Access database was on your machine.
   - if SQL Server is on a remote machine, most of the time will be spent on the network data transfer.
   - your bottleneck is probably not the database, it's the time to import that much data into the spreadsheet itself. You can try and execute the query from Access itself and see how long it takes.
4. If you have that much data to sift through, Excel is probably not the best tool for the job, and you may be better served by a dedicated reporting or Business Intelligence application.
   There are plenty of OpenSource and commercial platform, for instance:

   - http://www.pentaho.com/ (OpenSource + Commercial)
   - http://www.jaspersoft.com/  (OpenSource + Commercial)
   - http://www.gcpowertools.com/categories/Analysis (Commercial, for developers)

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. That is really helpful stuff. You're right when you say that the problem is not the query itself but actually the inport in excel. It all runs much faster in Access. I'll try using DAO like you suggested and if that fails too maybe I'll migrate to Access. On that note, `Set en = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine")` generates an error _"activex component can't create object"_. Any clue on how to fix that? Also, I see you removed the `rs.Open strSQL, cn, 0, 1
Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs` is this right? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Actually, I solved the _"activex component can't create object"_ with `Set en = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.36")`. Now I get a pop up asking to input or browse for a DSN. What is that? And how do I do it? I'm sorry, I'm really bad at this stuff!!

Comment: @Bruder: I updated the code a bit. Regarding the DAO exception, please check this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/157471

Comment: Lol, of course it didn't work, I copy/pasted your code omitting `strFile = "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\DataBase.accdb"`. I don't get prompted for a DSN anymore, but now another error pops up: "unrecognized database format". I used `Set en = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.36")`, as per the KB article you suggested (I have "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library"). I run office 2007. Any idea?

Comment: @Bruder: I have updated the code again with something that I could make work on my machine. Should be OK now.

Comment: I still get an error _"Undefined User Defined Type"_ with `Dim db As DAO.Database`.

Comment: @Bruder: you're probably not using to the proper reference to _Microsoft Office 12.0 Access database engine Object Library_. Be careful , there are a couple of libraries that have somewhat similar names. It must be this one exactly.

Comment: Ok, you were right again, I had the wrong reference (on a side note, I also had to remove Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library from the list as it created a name conflict error). It works now, but guess what? It's not that much of an improvement over the original code in my question. It took on average 6,26 seconds to extract ~460k rows with the original code and 6,77 with your code. It is faster with grouped records though: 19,9 sec for ~350k with original code, 19,0 with yours. So I guess this did help at least a little! Thank you for your help my friend!

Answer (score 2):

As you have surmised, the database is having to do more calculations, mainly because of your GROUP BY. Think what has to happen in your second query - the database needs to look at all ~600k rows before the first row can be returned, just in case the last row happens to have the earliest sorted customer. Although of course, the database can optimise this with an index on customer. However you are also applying the MONTH and YEAR functions to a field, and grouping on them, so again the database needs to do some work on every row before being able to work out the first row to return.

Your first query can almost immediately start returning data as it can just sequentially look through the sales db table returning each row as it matches on the region.

Since you are doing this on a single desktop the actual amount of data is probably not a big determinant of how long it takes overall. **(Later edit)** *Sorry that might be confusing. What I mean is that the total amount of data moved between the database and the excel spreadsheet is not the main determinant - the difference between moving 600k and 450k will not be that great. The main determinant is how much decision work the database has to do. However if you were transferring the data over a network (such as from a central sql server database), then the amount of data transferred would become a bigger factor in the overall time taken.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer Richard! Since the amount of data is not the issue here, I guess (like Dani pointed out above) that the software I use might be. Do you know any other route I can go to make this sort of task quicker?

Comment: You probably need to consider moving to sql server to get any significant performance improvements on such queries. Or more memory (especially if you can get the whole database into memory) or use SSD disks to store the access database on.